# Adding today date/time value into excel file using ant

Tags: ant

I'm using ant to get CSV files from an other ERP and send it into my SFDC system.
The batch will be every hour, so I used a script to move files to other dir each time a batch is finished

The issue that I want to rename those files to be the same name given but with date/time of NOW.

I found a rename script but I didn't managed to find any date time script to get the string value of date time - now

Comment: Please provide some code for us.  Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`<tstamp>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tstamp.html) to get the current date and time. Example:

```
<tstamp>
    <format property="TODAY" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
</tstamp>
<echo message="${TODAY}" />
```